# Can we delete the extra null rows?

Tags: sql-server

I have a result table that polls securities from the database, however, many securities have a duplicate that doesn't contain the full information (in this case they are missing the values of PX_MID, PX_ASK, and PX_BID). So is that possible we can get rid of those duplicates?  Please see the highlight parts, row 239 is the one I want to delete, and so does other similar duplicates. Thank you for your help!!!
[image]

Comment: Straight answer to your question is "yes, we can delete them". Otherwise please show us, what have you tried so far and explain problems with your approach (and do not expect someone to write code for you, this is not SO intention).

Comment: Can you alter the code which writes to this table, so it doesn't add these unwanted records in the first place? (That's assuming you mean they are entirely redundant for any purpose, as opposed to just not wanting them to appear in this particular query. It wasn't quite clear from the question which of those scenarios you mean).

Answer (score 0):

If I got the requirement right, we need to delete the entries (based on PortfolioCode, FMCID, IssueName) having `NULL`s in PX_MID, PX_ASK, and PX_BID but leave the entries if that's the only entry.

Ranking function can give us the value 1 for all NULL rows for the defined partition (PortfolioCode, FMCID, IssueName) and we can delete all those entries with rank 1 (after making sure that it is not the only entry).

try the following:

```
;with cte as
(
    select PortfolioCode, FMCID, IssueName, rank() over (partition by PortfolioCode, FMCID, IssueName order by PX_MID, PX_ASK, PX_BID) rn
    from @t
)

delete from cte
where PortfolioCode+FMCID+IssueName in
(
    select PortfolioCode+FMCID+IssueName
    from cte
    group by PortfolioCode+FMCID+IssueName
    having max(rn) > 1
)
and rn = 1
```

db<>fiddle **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e9c177d7f903b8f1d12077ad7a6e3355)**.

P.S.: We haven't considered the columns (Ticker to Outstanding_amount), assuming them all NULL. Please include as needed.

Comment: Hi, I'm going to be a little harsh and downvote this, because it doesn't explain the solution in a way that helps readers understand the general principle, and encourages future users to write poorly researched questions in the hope they'll get code written for them. In other words, while it might be useful for the author of this question, it is not helpful for the general quality of this site.

Comment: @IMSoP Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to explain the case by adding the details in the answer. Hope that will help.